# How to completely remove space between bottom of one line and top of the next line

Tags: line-spacing

Even when I try to set line spacing to zero, there's still a slight space between lines. What is causing it and how do I set this space to zero?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0cm}  % So that we can see the exact box around some text
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}  % Hairline box

\begin{document}

\noindent{\fontsize{1cm}{1cm}\selectfont \fbox{Foo}\\\fbox{Bar}}

\end{document}
```

[image: space between lines]

Comment: unrelated but `\noindent` doesn't take an argument in `{...}`

Comment: you want to get rid of the "interline skip"  specify (locally) `\nointerlineskip' .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `\setlength\lineskip{0pt}` (as in [David's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365936/116094)) still left a small gap, but `\nointerlineskip` (as in Barbara's comment to my question) removed the gap entirely.

A working example using `\nointerlineskip`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0cm}  % So that we can see the exact box around some text
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}  % Hairline box

\begin{document}
    \fontsize{1cm}{0.7cm}\selectfont 

    \noindent\fbox{One} \par \nointerlineskip \noindent\fbox{Two}

    % Or use whitespace instead of par:

    \noindent\fbox{Three} 

    \nointerlineskip
    \noindent\fbox{Four}
\end{document}
```

Result (zoomed in):

[image]

It's also possible to turn of interline skip globally by putting `\offinterlineskip` in the preamble at the beginning of the document section.

Also worth noting that `\nointerlineskip` doesn't work when you use `\\` to create line breaks. For instance, `foo \\ \nointerlineskip bar` would cause an error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `\lineskip` to 0 but also you hav especified a baselineskip of `cm but your box is smaller than that:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}



\setlength{\fboxsep}{0cm}  % So that we can see the exact box around some text
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}  % Hairline box

\begin{document}
\setlength\lineskip{0pt}
\fontsize{1cm}{.7cm}\selectfont 

\noindent\fbox{Foo}\\\fbox{Bar}


\bigskip

\noindent\fbox{\strut Foo}\\\fbox{\strut Bar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `\setlength\lineskip{0pt}` removes the spacing between the lines with struts, but there's still a small gap between the first foo and bar that don't have struts. Also, weirdly, using any figure other than 0.7cm in the `\fontsize` directive increases the gap. For instance, setting `\fontsize{1cm}{0cm}` leads to a larger gap than `\fontsize{1cm}{0.7cm}`